# При тестировании приложения на реальном устройстве все цвета не те, что были при тестировании на эмуляторе

Tags: android, recyclerview, android-sdk

Когда я тестирую своё приложение в Android Studio на эмуляторе, то всё отображается корректно, однако если я перекидываю его на своё реальное устройство, то некоторые цвета не те, что были в Android Studio. Подскажите, в чём может быть проблема?

Comment: для начала не помешает приложить разметку проблемного экрана, добавить скрины того что должно быть и что есть по факту, а то сейчас вы предлагаете чисто гипотетически допустить что у вас происходит

Comment: Таки поддержу коммент выше и попробую сделать предположение о том, что тестируете вы на относительно свежем Xiomi с включённым ночным режимом - это верно?

Comment: Если вы используете material3, то происходит то что и должно происходить.

Answer (score 1):

Проблема решена. Оказывается, у меня была включена темная тема на телефоне.